# High mountains surrounding lake in Africa, Nigeria. Similar to Spirit Island in Jasper National Park in Canada

Tags: identify-this, africa, tanzania, nigeria

I am writing a book where I must place a story on an island quite exactly the same as Spirit Island on Lake Maligne, Jasper National Park, Alberta, Canada:

[image]

(source: Microsoft Edge's background -- © Schroptschop / Getty Images)

But... in Africa (Nigeria or Tanzania the best). Is there any place there where high mountains are surrounding some lake with a small island on it? If yes, can you point me to an exact location?

<sub>(this is an ID-like question; the fact that I am asking for a place based on description shouldn't be a problem here, I think)</sub>

Comment: I'd look into the Mountains of the Moon in Uganda. Hilly, lots of lakes. Good chance there's an island in one of them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel

Comment: @mlc If I am not mistaken then I saw a lot of _your_ comments about VTC many questions, because they are not about travel. Are you sure that this site answers travel-related questions only? Did we descope identify-this questions recently? If so, why this isn't denoted in tag's description? Are visa-related questions or about spending a time between flights also OT? Are questions about plane layout or airport scheme also OT? Do we really want to do this page as narrow as travel-related only? A movement that started in SE network recently and is making more and more pages less and less valuable.

Comment: @trejder IMHO You start off by saying "I am writing a book .. ".  Ignoring the fact that it sounds like you are writing a fiction book, and thereby you don't need to have an actual location (see [Writinh.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com) for more on that), your question falls directly in the "what not to ask" as it it is a "find me a location" task - something that is explicitly called out as the type of question *not* to ask.

Comment: @PeterM While I totally agree with you on me bending the major rule here, I cannot (totally!) understand your base for an supposed assumption: "I am writing a book" → "This is a fiction book" (really, really surprising!). And furthermore: "fiction book" = "fiction place". I really _any_ "fiction" book forbid form happening in a real place? I am from Poland, where we have probably dozens of thousands of fiction books happing in actual places. I can name at least twenty books that happens in Africa, that has 100% of all people and events never existing and never ever happening". A bit weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at Google Maps (and it looks like it’s difficult to find any decent pictures at water level)

In Nigeria, I feel it’s going to be difficult, most of the country is pretty flat, except mountains to the southeast on the border with Cameroon, but very few lakes over there. The few lakes in the country are dam reservoirs.

- Kainji Reservoir: islands, but no mountains
- Shiroro Dam Reservoir: quite a few hills around (barely above 100m over the water level though), quite a few islands

In neighbouring Cameroon:

- Lake Bamendjing: islands, higher mountains but not right next to the lake.

Tanzania and neighbouring countries are probably better options. Lake Malawi for instance could be a candidate in some places (it’s a very large lake). There are quite a few other lakes and mountains around the country (and nearby), this could be a better starting point, though I doubt you would find exactly the same kind of relief found in Alberta.